# Time zone issue with day light saving in java

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, java-6

In my web application I am using **Google calendar**. Due to day light savings issue day light savings time is added when I saved the events in Google calendar through my application.

My application uses **Java 1.6**  and **Google calendar v3**.

What is the best solution to handle every time zone in the world?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the code where you get this date and store it into google calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use **SimpleDateFormat** class as stated [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.sg/2012/04/how-to-convert-local-time-to-gmt-in.html) before Java8

or may use **ZonedDateTime** in Java 8 as mentioned [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2015/03/20-examples-of-date-and-time-api-from-Java8.html)

Hope that helps.

Comment: My application uses java6 . SimpleDateFormat is not working .

Comment: My application uses java6 . For example if I use "GMT-08:00"  day light saving hours are not consider ,If I use "America/Los_Angeles" I will get correct time  after adding day light savings .

Comment: Yes, you need a full timezone to consider Daylight Savings. See this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones. And also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545960/how-to-tackle-daylight-savings-using-timezone-in-java

Comment: Ok . I will try in this way .Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help. You may want to accept the answer as 'accepted answer'.

Comment: where is the option provided ?

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green (see screenshot below)  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work