# How to convert GMT +09:00 to local time?

Tags: java, android, datetime, kotlin, android-jodatime

When I print date that I get from server, it shows `Mon Jun 24 16:15:31 GMT+09:00 2019`

```
val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
val date: Date? = formatter.parse(checkedDate) // date from server
val transformedDate = ("${String.format("%02d", date!!.month + 1)}.${String.format("%02d", date!!.date)}.${date.year + 1900}")
val title: String? = ("$transformedDate")

val longGmtTime = date.time
val mZone = TimeZone.getDefault()
val offset = mZone.getOffset(longGmtTime)
val longLocalTime = longGmtTime + offset - (9 * HOUR)

val localDate = Date() // local date
localDate.time = longLocalTime
val localFormatTime = formatter.format(localDate)
val transformedLocalDate = ("${String.format("%02d", localDate!!.month + 1)}.${String.format("%02d", localDate!!.date)}.${localDate.year + 1900}")
```

And it gives me `server time: 2019-06-24 16:15:31 -> 06.24.2019, local time(Asia/Seoul)-> 2019-06-25 01:15:30 ->06.25.2019` for the result.

The server time and local time must be the same. But the local time shows somewhere else.

What's the problem?

Comment: work in UTC and convert both?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If you don't receive a timezone with your timestamp, you have to consider it to be in local time.

Comment: What is it you want to do? Isn’t `Mon Jun 24 16:15:31 GMT+09:00 2019` already local time? Do you need to do anything at all? (apart from considering the modern date and time API)

Comment: That's server time. And I want to convert it to local time.

Comment: Related: (1) [Java Date and utcTimeOffset [closed\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51949842/java-date-and-utctimeoffset) (2) [Convert Time from one time zone to another using Java 8 Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962770/convert-time-from-one-time-zone-to-another-using-java-8-time)

Comment: I assume the downvotes are either because it’s not clear what you want or because the question seems poorly researched. I didn’t understand the question until I tried running your code myself and saw the results. And as hinted in my previous comment, there are similar questions and answers already that could probably have helped you before you asked your question (there are many more than the two I linked to).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the problem?

The gross problem list includes:

- You are using the poorly designed and long outdated Java date and time classes `Date`, `TimeZone` and `SimpleDateFormat`.
- You are using the deprecated methods `getMonth`, `getDate` and `getYear` of the `Date` class. These methods work unreliably across time zone, which is the main reason why they were deprecated.
- You are doing the time zone conversion manually using addition, subtraction and multiplication. Date and time math is error-prone, and you should always leave it to proven library methods.
- The millisecond count you get from `Date.getTime` is since the epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00 UTC. This is a unique moment in time and independent of time zone, so adding to and subtracting from the millisecond count for time zone conversion makes no sense.
- I can reproduce your result when I set my JVM’s default time zone to Asia/Seoul and assume that `HOUR` is 0 (or some value in the range from 0 through 111). I assume that you had wanted `HOUR` to denote the number of milliseconds in an hour, 3 600 000 (at least usually, exceptions exist).
- You were formatting your date by concatenating the results of calls to `Strirg.format`. It’s better to leave formatting to a specialized date formatter.

### The fix: java.time

```
    ZoneId serverTimeZone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Seoul");
    DateTimeFormatter serverFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    ZoneId clientTimeZone = ZoneId.systemDefault();

    String checkedDate = "2019-06-24 16:15:31";
    ZonedDateTime serverDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(checkedDate, serverFormatter)
            .atZone(serverTimeZone);
    ZonedDateTime clientDateTime = serverDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(clientTimeZone);
    System.out.println("clientDateTime: " + clientDateTime);
```

Sorry that I can write and run only Java code, I trust you to translate. With my JVM’s time zone still set to Asia/Seoul I get:

> clientDateTime: 2019-06-24T16:15:31+09:00[Asia/Seoul]

The server time and the client time are the same, as you requested. If instead I keep my own time zone, I get:

> clientDateTime: 2019-06-24T09:15:31+02:00[Europe/Copenhagen]

So there is a conversion taking place.

To format the date:

```
    DateTimeFormatter displayFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
            .withLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("ko-KR"));
    String transformedLocalDate = clientDateTime.format(displayFormatter);
    System.out.println("transformedLocalDate: " + transformedLocalDate);
```

> transformedLocalDate: 2019. 6. 24.

Or if you insist on month.date.year:

```
    DateTimeFormatter displayFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM.dd.u");
```

> transformedLocalDate: 06.24.2019

A further recommendation would be to have your server deliver a date-time string in UTC in ISO 8601 format. That would go like `2019-06-24T07:15:31Z` for the moment used in the examples.

### Question: Can I use java.time with minSdk API level 23 on Android?

Yes, java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: That way requires minSdk API 26. My minSdk is API 23. Is there any alternative way..?

Comment: It doesn’t require API level 26. With API level 23 it requires the ThreeTenABP library. Just read until the end of the answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should specify setup server timezone instead of you device (which is default)

Comment: Could you explain it in detail?