# DateUtils.addDays() class issue in daylight saving time

Tags: java, date, datetime, timezone, simpledateformat

Recently New Zealand observed daylight saving on 27 sept 15.

```
SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
sd.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Pacific/Auckland"));
Date dateValue = sd.parse("2015-09-30");
System.out.println(dateValue); // prints "Tue Sep 29 07:00:00 EDT 2015" My local system timzone in EDT 
dateValue = DateUtils.addDays(dateValue, -6); // 6 days back 24 Sep of  Pacific/Auckland
System.out.println(dateValue); // prints "Tue Sep 23 07:00:00 EDT 2015"
```

The second print statement should print `Tue Sep 29 08:00:00 EDT 2015`, as Daylight Saving not is in effect.

The issue is before 27 Sep 15 NZ = UTC+12 
and after NZ = UTC +13 
So on date of 23 Sep It should have time `08:00:00` not `07:00:00`

Comment: What is `DateUtils.addDays`? Is it from a library?

Comment: Any reason why you can't use java 8s time API joda time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tackle daylight savings using Timezone in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545960/how-to-tackle-daylight-savings-using-timezone-in-java)

Comment: DateUtils.addDays is apache common lang 2.6 library which i used And i can use jdk1.7 only

Comment: @MiteshParmar Please furnish additional information as edits to your Question rather than as comments. And provide links to the various involved libraries as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is within `DateUtils.addDays` from Apache Commons: it is using a `Calendar` with the default timezone to add and subtract days instead of using a user-supplied timezone. You can see this in the source code of the method [`add`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.java#DateUtils.add%28java.util.Date%2Cint%2Cint%29): it calls `Calendar.getInstance()` and not `Calendar.getInstance(someTimezone)`

If you construct yourself the `Calendar` and set the correct timezone, the problem disappears:

```
SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
sd.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Pacific/Auckland"));
Date dateValue = sd.parse("2015-09-30");
System.out.println(dateValue); // prints "Tue Sep 29 13:00:00 CEST 2015"

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Pacific/Auckland")); // set correct timezone to calendar
calendar.setTime(dateValue);
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -6);
dateValue = calendar.getTime();
System.out.println(dateValue); // prints "Wed Sep 23 14:00:00 CEST 2015"
```

Answer (score 1):

also i have used joda api to resolved this timezone issue.

```
org.joda.time.DateTimeZone timeZone = org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID( "Pacific/Auckland" );
    DateTime currentDate= new DateTime( new Date(), timeZone );
DateTime dateValue = now.plusDays( -6 ); // prints Tue Sep 29 08:00:00 EDT 2015
```

Comment: In Java 8 and later, you can use the new built-in [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework. These new classes were inspired by Joda-Time and are intended to be its successor.