# TimeZone offset shows invalid value

Tags: java, date, timezone

Unless I do something wrong...

I live in Poland (GMT+2). By the time I write this we are in daylight saving time. The following code, however, says that the GMT time offset is only 1 hour instead of 2.

```
  Calendar mCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
  TimeZone mTimeZone = mCalendar.getTimeZone();
  System.out.println(mTimeZone);
  int mGMTOffset = mTimeZone.getRawOffset();
  System.out.printf("GMT offset is %s hours", TimeUnit.HOURS.convert(mGMTOffset, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
```

prints  GMT offset is 1 hours

Same happens for other timezones, for example New York, which is GMT-4:

```
Calendar mCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
```

prints GMT offset is -5 hours

Comment: check here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545960/how-to-tackle-daylight-savings-using-timezone-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two methods the TimeZone you have to use:

you can check if the a date is in DaylightSaveTime with:

```
mTimeZone.inDaylightTime(date)
```

And if this is True you have to add the value of

```
mTimeZone.getDSTSavings()
```

to the Offset:

```
Calendar mCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
TimeZone mTimeZone = mCalendar.getTimeZone();
System.out.println("TimeZone: "+mTimeZone);
int mGMTOffset = mTimeZone.getRawOffset();
if (mTimeZone.inDaylightTime(mCalendar.getTime())){
    mGMTOffset += mTimeZone.getDSTSavings();
}
System.out.printf("GMT offset is %s hours", 
TimeUnit.HOURS.convert(mGMTOffset, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
```

output:

```
GMT offset is 2 hours
```

Answer (score 1):

Check whether DST is active in java .

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
boolean inDs = tz.inDaylightTime(new Date());
```

Below code give you with DST time

```
TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
DateFormat format = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
format.setTimeZone(zone);

System.out.println(format.format(new Date()));
```