# java.sql.Time to OffsetTime

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, t-sql, time

Hi in DB i have four columns to store a time window. This would allow user to store 9:00 to 5:00 EST.

Now i need to parse this information in java.

```
java.sql.Time startTS = rs.getTime("begin_TIME ");
LocalTime localTime = startTS.toLocalTime();
```

offset could be made with:
OffsetTime of(LocalTime time, ZoneOffset offset)

from what i see we cant convert zoneid to zoneoffset, so how do i 9:00 est(stored in time and zone columns) from sqlserver to java.

```
DB Table:
 begin_TIME time NOT NULL,
 begin_TIME_ZONE varchar(5) NOT NULL,
 end_TIME time NOT NULL,
 end_TIME_ZONE varchar(5) NOT NULL,
```

In the back-end I need to check that the request is in the window, request time is converted to ZonedDateTime and start and end need to come from DB:

```
public boolean compare(ZonedDateTime dateTime, OffsetTime startTime, OffsetTime endTime) {
    OffsetTime offsetTime = dateTime.toOffsetDateTime().toOffsetTime();
    int start = offsetTime.compareTo(startTime);
    int end = offsetTime.compareTo(endTime);
    return start >= 0 && end <= 0;
}
```

Comment: When you say EST, you mean Eastern Standard Time? Would daylight savings time be marked by `begin_TIME_ZONE` or `end_TIME_ZONE` being `EDT` instead of `EST`?

Comment: no its not expected that user will go and change time zones for daylight savings. user needs to define 9-5 Toronto time(EST) or 9-5 pacfic time. in the back end, java need to adjust for daylight savings.
Database schema is open to change if that helps.

Comment: Three-letter time zone IDs are going out of use. It may not make the big difference for your question, but I might consider using for example `America/Toronto`. Something that feeds directly into `ZoneId.of()`. Well, this was probably an aside.

Comment: How is the backend going to be able to adjust for daylight savings when there is no date attached? How can it determine whether daylight savings is in effect?

Comment: sure, but even if we have zoneId from America/Toronto, we don't have ZoneOffset

Comment: In the back end i need to check request is in window, request time is converted to ZonedDateTime  and start and end need to come from DB

`public boolean compare(ZonedDateTime dateTime, OffsetTime startTime, OffsetTime endTime) {

  OffsetTime offsetTime = dateTime.toOffsetDateTime().toOffsetTime();

  int start = offsetTime.compareTo(startTime);
  int end = offsetTime.compareTo(endTime);

  return start >= 0 && end <= 0;

 }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138151/discussion-between-ole-v-v-and-tsingh).

Comment: Can your date-times come from all over the world? When in Sydney, Australia (AEDT) it’s Thu, 16 Mar 2017 08:15, it is Wed, 15 Mar 2017 14:15 in San Fransicco, California (PDT). So this would be will inside a 9 to 5 window, but because the dates are not the same, my code in my answer below will fail to recognize that. Is it a requirement to take this situation into account?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your situation right, this variant of your `compare` method should be able to help you:

```
public boolean compare(ZonedDateTime dateTime, LocalTime start, ZoneId startTz,
        LocalTime end, ZoneId endTz) {
    ZonedDateTime startZonedDateTime = start.atDate(dateTime.toLocalDate()).atZone(startTz);
    ZonedDateTime endZonedDateTime = end.atDate(dateTime.toLocalDate()).atZone(endTz);
    return (! dateTime.isBefore(startZonedDateTime)) && (! dateTime.isAfter(endZonedDateTime));
}
```

I am using the date part of the supplied `ZonedDateTime` to determine whether the comparison is to be made on a date where daylight saving time is in effect. I chose so because Java needs a date to be able to convert a local time to a zoned or offset time when the time zone may have daylight savings time.

It is possible to compare `OffsetTime` (ignoring dates) objects as you do in your version, but I found it somewhat simpler to compare `ZonedDateTime` objects instead. What it really does is compare the corresponding instants, so it works well even though the time zones differ.

I trust you to supply the two zone ID objects to the method. If you end up storing time zones as `America/Toronto` in your database, this can be fed directly into `ZoneId.of()`.

I really don’t think you should stick to `EST` and `PST`. It’s getting too complicated and errorprone. Java can translate `EST` to `-05:00`; this leaves you with no adjustment for daylight savings time (it does understand `PST` as `America/Los_Angeles` though). Use the modern forms `America/Toronto` etc. See the answers to [this question: How to tackle daylight savings using Timezone in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545960/how-to-tackle-daylight-savings-using-timezone-in-java).