# Handle DST in UTC time using Groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to convert milliseconds time to date-time (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z') format in UTC.

```
def StartDateTimeNew = testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("StartDateTime").toLong()
def Startdate = new Date(StartDateTimeNew).format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'));
log.info Startdate
```

'StartDateTime' value is '1503478800000'

The output i am getting is :-

```
Tue Aug 22 18:13:59 IST 2017:INFO:2017-08-23T09:00:00Z
```

But i want to handle DST in the output :-

```
Tue Aug 22 18:13:59 IST 2017:INFO:2017-08-23T10:00:00Z
```

Comment: How about this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545960/how-to-tackle-daylight-savings-using-timezone-in-java

Comment: How to know the timezone name? like for EST we have 'America/New_York', What name used for UTC?

Comment: Did below solution help?

Comment: Date format is different, not tried. I want some simple change in my existing code. The link you provided is good but cannot find the UTC timezone name.

Comment: Raj, how are you testing it now? there is no `DST` active now?

Comment: The time i receive in Output is 1 hr less than actual UK time.

Comment: Try `UTC/Greenwich` for `UTC` if that helps.

Comment: Nope. Output is still same.

Comment: This works `def Startdate = new Date(StartDateTimeNew).format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", TimeZone.getTimeZone('GMT+1'));`

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Java 8, I'd highly recommend using its new java.time API instead of java.util.Date

```
import java.time.*
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

// this converts the millis to the ZonedDateTime representation
def currentZone = ZoneId.systemDefault() // or whatever the appropriate zone is
def startdate = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(startDateTimeLong), currentZone)

// to format in UTC
def fmt = startdate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.withZone(ZoneId.of('UTC')))
```