# DateTime to java.sql.timestamp conversion is adding +1 hour

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp, jodatime, date-conversion

I am calling my `rest` api with following url `localhost:8080/api/2016-05-30T10:30:00-05:00/3`

The api receives `date` as `String` and then convert it into jodatime datetime object like `dateTime = DateTime.parse(date);` ... debugging this code shows that its resulting in expected value.

However, when i am converting this date to `java.sql.timestamp` like `Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(dateTime.getMillis());` ... the resulting time is `2016-05-30 11:30:00.0` ... why is it adding `+1 hour` to the time and whats the proper way to convert ?

***SOME BACKGROUND***

I have saved the time as timestamp in sql table. with timezone (as a string +4:00 or -5:00 for example) in a separate column.

I would receive an `ISO8601` time in my url path parameter and based on that I have to fetch the record from db. For that, I will be using two comparison. 1 to match the time and 2 to match the timezone.

Comment: You might want to include information about the timezone. It can often have ... interesting side effects.

Comment: What information shall i add ? I am not doing anything explicit per say ... my system is set to EDT Time zone though

Comment: I'm not familiar with jodatime but `java.sql.Timestamp(long)` expects the argument to be in GMT timezone and I don't see any timezone specified in the [`BaseDateTime.getMillis()` javadoc](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/BaseDateTime.html#getMillis%28%29), though it appears to be using ISO8601, which Z means UTC, which is equivalent ot GMT...

Comment: Did you try with `java.util.Date(long)` as well?

Comment: You are currently on daylight savings time, which advances your clock one hour... can't be a coincidence.

Comment: I know but what i am trying to figure out is an absoluate way to convert JodaTime to `java.sql.timestamp` so that i can execute the query.

Comment: @EmAe it seems there is none, as DST messes it up (not handled in ISO 8601).

Comment: ... or actually you're doing it right: using the `Timestamp(long)` constructor.

Comment: I have updated my answer with information about `Timezone.inDaylightTime()` method that might be useful in your case.

Answer (score 1):

The [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) states that

> ... the time in New York in *winter* is UTC−05:00

So it seems [daylight saving time](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) is *not* included in the date string, which means what you get is the correct time, as per the defined timezone (`-05:00`). New York *summer* time should be `-04:00`, as DST is not part of ISO 8601.

You could add an extra DST column in your database or add it as a parameter, or go through the process of checking whether you are in DST, which varies country to country (e.g. Qatar does not uses it) and year by year (e.g Russia has abandoned DST a few years ago), so it's not a viable option...

EDIT:
Another option would be for you to test if the Timezone is currently in DST, as indicated in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1060511/1098603). You could then apply the -1h offset.

Note that Joda has a [`minusHours()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#minusHours%28int%29) method you can use, if [`inDaylightTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#inDaylightTime%28java.util.Date%29) returns `true`.